# grep on lynx command

Tags: bash, shell, lynx

I want to grep the result on lynx command

```
lynx -head -dump http://abdsadsac.org
```

Result for that command

```
Looking up 111.111.111.111:9004
Making HTTP connection to 111.111.111.111:9004
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://abdsadsac.org
```

I want that word replace to be 0 or down, I try to create bash script, but that command still shown. Result that i want is.

```
#lynx -head -dump http://abdsadsac.org
Down
```

Already try to use if else on the bash but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the exit code to determine if the site is up?

For example:

```
$ lynx -head -dump http://abdsadsac.org 2> /dev/null || echo Down
Down
```